# Joining values in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array that contains hashes as below. I am trying to join just the text portion of these hashes and this the best I came up.

```
array_hashes = [{"seq"=>0, "text"=>"got"},
                {"type"=>"ignore", "seq"=>1, "text"=>"to"}, 
                {"seq"=>2, "text"=>"go"}]

a = Array.new
array_hashes.each {|h| a << h["text"]}
a.join("-")

=> got-to-go
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
array_hashes = [{"seq"=>0, "text"=>"got"},
                {"type"=>"ignore", "seq"=>1, "text"=>"to"}, 
                {"seq"=>2, "text"=>"go"}]
array_hashes.map{|h| h['text']}.join("-")
# => "got-to-go"
```

Comment: If you start with an enumberable object (like Hash or Array) and you want another array where each item is transformed in some way, `map` is usually exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I had the exact same code as @Arup Rakshit's at first but with a "each" and it simply kept returning the original array back. Map it is!